# Make a following gif, from the point in 3D

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I want to make a gif like this
[image]

I tried:

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.008], White, Point@Tuples[Range[10], 3]}, 
Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 500, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

How can I zoom in and rotate it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.008], White, Point@Tuples[Range[10], 3]}, 
  Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> 500, 
  Boxed -> False,
  ViewPoint -> {x, y, z}],
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```